# How do I display text on buttons in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio have about 50 buttons visible on the screen at all times but I do not know what they mean because I cannot differentiate most buttons based on icons alone.

Here is an example view of part of the screen:

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio showing "Live Share" button and a bunch of unknown other buttons]

Some of the buttons have text, but most do not. Is there a way to activate text for all buttons?

Comment: Mouse-over the buttons to see the tooltips?

Comment: _"Is there a way to activate text for all buttons?"_ - **kinda**: you can write a VS Extension that manipulates the runtime XAML to make button text visible, but this won't be supported by VS at all. For an example, see one of my favourite extensions which brings-back icons to tool-tabs: https://github.com/olegtarasov/VSIconizer

Comment: Adding the text there would use a lot of screen space. It won't be fitting into a single row, so it will either require multiple rows or an overlap area - not very useful IMHO. If you don't recognize the icons, just don't use them - everything can be done without the buttons as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of a built-in way to display the text for ALL buttons.

You can however do it for most, but not all, individual buttons.

1. Right-click anywhere on the main toolbar and select "Customize" from the context menu.
2. Switch to "Commands" tab, check "Toolbar" and select a toolbar which you want to customize, for example, "Standard".
3. In the Preview, select the button you want to customize and press the "Modify selection":
   [image]
4. Change style to "Image and text":
   [image]

That's all, the button has the text now:
[image]

Unfortunately, it seems you cannot do this for the toolbar in Solution explorer, from your screenshot. You would need an extension for this.

Answer (score 2):

By using another instance of Visual Studio you can attach its debugger to the first instance, then use the runtime XAML editing tools to make elements visible or alter other properties too.

Like so:

[image]

---

1. Ensure your current instance of `devenv.exe` is idle.
2. Open another instance of `devenv.exe` and attach the .NET Framework 4.x debugger to the first instance:

   1. In the *second instance* of `devenv.exe` (with no Solution loaded), go
      <kbd>Debug</kbd> > <kbd>Attach to Process</kbd>.
   2. Ensure the "Attach to:" field is set to "Managed (.NET 4.x)". Ensure "Native", "Script", "Managed (.NET Core, .NET 5+)", "Managed (.NET 3.x, 2.x)", and "Managed Compatibility Mode" are all unchecked.

   - [image]
3. After the *second instance* is finished attaching (loading symbols, etc), open the "Live Visual Tree" window (under <kbd>Debug</kbd> > <kbd>Windows</kbd> > <kbd>Live Visual Tree</kbd>).
4. ...and use the "Select Element..." tool, then click on the Solution Explorer toolbar in the *first instance* of Visual Studio:

   [image]
5. And you should see something like this (`PART_ToolBarPanel [VsToolBarPanel]`):

   [image]
6. For each `VsButton` button you want the text for...

   1. Expand it in the Live Visual Tree and look for its `Text [AccessText]` child.

      - For most buttons this is 3 levels deep, but some (like Split buttons) have the `AccessText` element buried deeper.
   2. Open the Live Property Explorer and set Local > Visibility from `Collapsed` to `Visible`.

Comment: Interesting to see how to debug Visual Studio but ultimately pointless as any changes you make during your debug session will be lost the next time you launch Visual Studio (or is there some way to persist them?)